# Resizing WPF windows according to the size of the screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a multi window application, which fills the entire screen, I want it to be usable on all screen sizes, so I would like to resize it according to the screen size. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does your app have one top-level window containing multiple windows (like Visual Studio) or does it have several top-level windows (like VB3 or the GIMP)?

Comment: Actually I have a background window and several top layer windows over it, I had to make the program quickly so I didn't mess around with children windows, but if you have a quick solution for it just write it.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your intent, but can you not just maximize the window? Why does the window which "fills the entire screen" need to be resized?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Screen.GetWorkingArea method to return a rectangle object which represents the screen area available. You should be able to use this information to decide where to place your screen elements.

Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a92hss5.aspx